# How to run two different versions of an API with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently working on an application in Node.js, that consists of a front-end making http requests to a backend API. What I need to do is have multiple versions of that API with a version number I can pass through and that will then change which version of an API call is made.

The backend is already written so I can't now change that (I thought of using restify but it would be far too much work to convert). So I was wondering if anyone had tried to do something similar where there are multiple versions of the API?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Did you try something yet? Can post your sample code?

Comment: How about `app.use('/api/v1', require('./api/v1/routedefinitions'));`?

Comment: @str that sounds perfect, we're going to try that approach, cheers.